# Logrotate appending file name with a “.1”

Tags: logrotate

For some reason our tomcatlogs are being appended with a .1 when logrotate runs. e.g: file "tcl-2013-08-16.0.log" becomes "tcl-2013-08-16.0.1.log". I am struggling to find what setting is adding the ".1" before the ".log" part of the file name. Below is a copy of the settings file from /etc/logrotate.d/:

```
extension .log
rotate 52
daily
nocreate
nodateext
missingok
notifempty
compress
delaycompress
```

Below is the config in /etc/logrotate.conf:

```
weekly
rotate 52  
create  
dateext  
compress  
delaycompress  
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks, Nath

Comment: nodateext == `Do not archive old versions of log files with date extension (this overrides the dateext option).`  datext == `Archive old versions of log files adding a daily extension like YYYYMMDD instead of simply adding a number. The extension may be configured using the dateformat option.`  So you are telling it to add the number